# Using \textstyle with \pmod

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, displaystyle

If I'm in a displayed equation but I want the `\sum` symbol to appear as it does in inline formulas, I can just put `\textstyle` in my equation. I thought that writing `\textstyle` would also force `\pmod` to use the spacing it uses for inline formulas, but for some reason it won't work. Why is that, and how can I force `\pmod` to use the non-display style spacing when I'm in a displayed equation?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is inline math: $ \sum {a\pmod b} $

This is display math: \[ \sum {a\pmod b} \]

This is display math with $\backslash$textstyle: \[ \textstyle \sum {a\pmod b} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `amsmath` display environments set `\if@display` to true, but `\textstyle` has no influence over it, so you get the `\mkern18mu` nonetheless. You either want to modify the definition of `\pod` or to define a variant `\tpmod` command. By the way it should be `\sum a\pmod{b}`.

Comment: @egreg okay, so you're suggesting I use a `\mathchoice` command?

Comment: Not at all; I suggest using `\tpmod` defined like `\newcommand{\tpmod}[1]{\mkern 8mu({\operator@font mod}\mkern 6mu#1)}`

Comment: @egreg that looks like an answer:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `amsmath` package sets `\if@display` to true in displays; the primitive `\textstyle` has no influence over it. Since the standard definition of `\pmod` checks `\if@display`, you get the additional space nonetheless.

You have two strategies available. First strategy: redefine `\pod` (which `\pmod` depends on) so it doesn't add the space. This can be done with

```
\renewcommand{\pod}[1]{\allowbreak\mkern 8mu(#1)}
```

You should also change `\mod` to be consistent:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mod}[1]{\allowbreak\mkern 12mu{\operator@font mod}\,\,#1}
\makeatother
```

Second strategy. If you want to be able to choose between the standard spacing and the reduced one, define a new command

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tpmod}[1]{\mkern 8mu({\operator@font mod}\mkern 6mu#1)}
\makeatother
```